# find index of certain array that is inside array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Is there a way to find an index of an array inside another array without converting them to list or using a for loop?

I have a huge data set and I don't want to add another loop and make it slower

```
arr = np.array([[11, 19, 18], [14, 15, 11], [19, 21, 46], [29, 21, 19]])
find_this_array = np.array([14, 15, 11])

# I want to avoid this
a = arr.tolist()
val = find_this_array.tolist()
a.index(val)
```

output:

```
1
```

Comment: What other data structures have you considered? Hard to say without context, but you might need to reshape your data set to support efficient access to the data in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
np.where((arr == find_this_array).all(axis=1))[0][0]
```

output:

```
1
```

You can find more details about Numpy `where` from their documentation:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html